# How to do HTTP binding for Openfire plugin

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, openfire

I'm using Openfire as the chat server for my company. And now I need to create a plugin for Openfire.

As I can see from other plugins, they can have HTTP binding to themself through port 7070.
For example: http://example.com:7070/redfire where **redfire** is the name of the plugin.

The name of my plugin is **toplug**, so I want to be able to access the JSP pages of my plugin through: http://example.com:7070/toplug/index.jsp where 'index.jsp' is some example page.

But when I try to access my JSP pages through port 7070, the Jetty server (on which Openfire runs) always reports error 404 'page not found'. I guess this is because the binding to my folder which contains JSP pages hasn't been set. How to do this binding thing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is answered here:
http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/224134

You do not need a plugin to access the web service for the http bing port. Just put your web pages in a folder under:
 
**OPENFIRE_HOME/openfire/resources/spank**

and access with:
http://example.com:7070/your_folder/your_page.html

Note that Openfire does not compile JSP pages unless you replace jasper-xxxx.jar files in the lib folder.

If you still want to create a jetty web context (application) from your plugin, see source code of Redfire plugin:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;     
...

public void initializePlugin(PluginManager manager,File pluginDirectory) {
  ContextHandlerCollection contexts = 
  HttpBindManager.getInstance().getContexts();

  context = new WebAppContext(contexts,pluginDirectory.getPath(),"/"+NAME);
  context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});
...
```